# Is Hashmap becomes link list if I constantly return same hashcode for every object

Tags: java

I am aware of hashmap internal implementation, the point which I need to understand is that, suppose I have a `class Student` and I have provided a bad implementation of `hashcode()` so it always return 1.

Now suppose I have snippet below

```
Student s1=new Student("Jack");
Student s2=new Student("James");
Student s3=new Student("John");
.
.
.
.
.
till `n` times

Map<Student,String> studentMap=new HashMap<>();
studentMap.put(s1,"1000");
studentMap.put(s2,"1001");
studentMap.put(s3,"1002");
.
.
.
.
.
till `n` times
```

as we know `put()` method internally called `hashcode()` in order to find the bucket position, now for every `Student` object the hashcode is equal, so there will be hashcode Collison occurs and whatever the bucket position has been calculated before, the long record link list has been constructed on the same for all the `Student` objects.

Now if it becomes link list so the `get()` becomes expensive, because for each object having same hashcode it must traverse every node of link list to get the value of input `key`, so here it seems the purpose is violated as the performance degraded

So I just want to know whether the implementation is working like this or I need to correct my understanding. Please suggest me the best articles ,posts or answers which will provide me the end to end clarity of such conceptual scenarios.

Comment: Yes, they will be placed all in the same bucket with the "linked list" problematic you have mentioned.

Comment: then how to get rid of this, apart from good impementation of hashcode(), what is the best alternative collection we have in java to deal such scenario

Comment: @user9634982: the only practical alternative is to implement `Comparable` and use `TreeMap` to guarantee O(log n) time -- though once you've implemented `Comparable`, then modern versions of `HashMap` will also degrade to a `TreeMap` instead of a linked list.

Comment: Okay, could you please post some relevant code to achieve the same, that how one can mimic the `Treemap` by implementing `Comparable` for above scenario

Comment: @jack after yet more consideration, still seems to me implementing hash code correctly seems the best option-- three lines of code versus the tens provided in the accepted answer. Is pointing that out not contributing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the HashMap implementation is like you described. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html):

> Note that using many keys with the same hashCode() is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table. To ameliorate impact, when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties.

Here a simple example of how the implementation of `hashCode` and `Comparable` make difference in the `HashMap` performance:

```
class Student {
    protected final String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class StudentComparable extends Student implements Comparable<StudentComparable> {
    public StudentComparable(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentComparable o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}

class StudentHashcode extends Student {
    public StudentHashcode(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

When running this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int records = 20000;

        System.out.println("Run #1: Without comparable nor hashCode");
        populateMap(records, Student::new);

        System.out.println("Run #2: With comparable");
        populateMap(records, StudentComparable::new);

        System.out.println("Run #3: With hashCode");
        populateMap(records, StudentHashcode::new);
    }

    public static void populateMap(int records, Function<String, Student> builder){
        Map<Student, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(records);
        Student last = null;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
            last = builder.apply("Student:" + i);
            map.put(last, i);
        }
        System.out.println("Insert took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        map.get(last);
        System.out.println("Get took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
```

Give this output on my laptop, running OpenJDK 15:

```
Run #1: Without comparable
Insert took: 6573
Get took: 1

Run #2: With comparable
Insert took: 132
Get took: 0

Run #3: With hashCode
Insert took: 26
Get took: 0
```

Comment: Okay, could you please post some relevant code to achieve the same, that how one can mimic the `Treemap` by implementing `Comparable` for above scenario

Comment: @user9634982 I've add a `Comparable` implementation example in the answer.